# I wrote 10 articles in ABC Magazine vs. I wrote 10 articles for ABC Magazine

Tags: prepositions

I want to include my past work experience in my resume and am not sure about the right preposition for the sentence above.

Comment: If they were published, you can say I have had 10 articles published in ABC Magazine.  To say you wrote 10 articles *for* ABC magazine does not necessarily imply they were accepted by or published in the magazine.

Comment: You might want to try Workplace.SE - They might warn you not to brag with numbers and just say *published in*. That's just my take; this is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

As Kristina Lopez observes in a comment above, the proper choice of wording depends on what actually happened to the ten articles you refer to.

> I wrote ten articles for ABC Magazine

means that you wrote ten articles with the idea of submitting them to ABC Magazine for publication. It does not mean that ABC Magazine actually published all ten articles, or even one of the ten; but it strongly implies that you wrote them at the behest of or with the approval of the magazine—and in the normal order of things, that wouldn't happen if the magazine were serially rejecting your submissions.

> I wrote ten articles that were published in ABC Magazine [or "that ABC Magazine published"]

removes any doubt about how many of your submissions the magazine published. It doesn't indicate how many articles you submitted (the number could be larger than ten), but that issue is beside the point when when you are focusing on your number of successful submissions, rather than on your percentage of accepted submissions.

> I wrote ten articles in ABC Magazine

isn't idiomatic in U.S. English, and I'm fairly sure that it isn't idiomatic in other varieties of English either. The normal prepositional forms in this situation are as follows: you wrote articles **for** the magazine or **for** publication **in** the magazine, and the articles were published **in** the magazine.

Comment: Additional thought: "I wrote ten articles in ABC Magazine" could mean several things.  "Of all the articles appearing in ABC Magazine, I wrote 10 of them", or "I used ABC Magazine as scrap paper and wrote ten articles in it".

Comment: I would actually argue that *for* is more impressive because it implies being commissioned. To write an article in a magazine means that you wrote it and now it is in it. You could have submitted yourself. *For* means the magazine asked you to write then, which is a higher honor.